# Numbers choosing algorithm form constants according to input

Tags: algorithm-analysis

First of all sorry for my poor English.

Problem:
There are 15 strings 1 to 50 and they’ve defined randomly. 
There is a input 1 to 500. 
This 15 strings are static but input is changing during 75k iteration. 
At each iteration computer will pick some of 15 strings which are nearest value to input when they summarise. 
Goal is end of the 75 k iteration sum of difference between summarise of picked number and the input is 2%. Or nearest point.

Barriers: computer cannot pick a number if that number picked in last 60 iterations.

Outputs:
Nearest point of goal and an analyse what would be the best 15 numbers accordingly that inputs.

Comment: If it is possible at all, please edit the question to add a reference, even if it is in an obscure language.

Comment: Can you give a simple but non-trivial example with 3 strings and 10 iterations?

Comment: Can you edit the question to credit the source where you originally encountered this problem?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercise-style problems or programming-contest-style problems for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: What does it mean "input is changing"?  What do you mean by "nearest"?  How do you plan to measure distance/nearness?  What do you mean by "sum of difference between summarise of picked number and the input is 2%"?  What is "summarise"?  What is the sum taken over?  Is there a different input provided at each input?  Does the algorithm have to pick the nearest string or can it pick some other one?  In each iteration, does it have to pick a string immediately  after seeing the input; or can it wait until it has seen all 75K inputs, then pick 75K strings at the end?

Comment: What does "Nearest point of goal" mean?  What does "the best 15 numbers accordingly that inputs" mean?  Sorry, I am having difficulty understanding the statement of the problem.  I encourage you to edit the question to explain the problem statement.  I appreciate that it is difficult to write in a language that you do not know.  Thank you for trying!